# Angular: Token error when expression passed to custom directive with isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

(messages, code, etc, is a bit modified to explain issue)

The error:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'promiseObject' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{promiseObject?promiseObject.activeDEM:0}}] starting at [promiseObject?promiseObject.activeDEM:0}}].
```

Following code explains the issue:

HTML used:

```
<count-up id="feafdcds" duration="1" end-val='{{promiseObject?promiseObject.value:0}}' class="number" ></count-up>
```

The directive used has an isolated scope. if isolated scope is removed, the error goes away, BUT, then I don't know how to watch my attributes for change.

```
angular.module('core-metronic').directive('countUp', ['$filter',
    function ($filter) {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                endVal: '='
            },
            link: function ($scope, $el, $attrs) {
                $scope.$watch('endVal',function(newValue,oldValue)
                {
                    if(newValue)
                        alert(newValue); 
                },true);

                //...more code...

            }

        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: '=' is two-way binding but you are passing an expression. Perhaps that is causing issue.

Comment: probably. Any alternative way I can do what I'm trying to do? i.e reload/rerun/or-something the directive once the promise object is resolved

Comment: What happens when you change your scope so that endVal: '&'

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Or expand this:  https://jsfiddle.net/yvgxycuw/

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis Thanks for that :).
Here is a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ks3ft42/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the angular two-way-binding

```
endVal: '='
```

with an angular expression

```
{{promiseObject?promiseObject.value:0}}
```

When you use two-way-binding angular tries in case of a value change to set that new value to the binded variable.
in your case what you want to bind to endVal is not a variable but an expression. so angular does not know what to do with this.

You have two options:

1. In case you DO NOT need the value of endVal outside of the directive you can 
   use

   `endVal: '@'`

instead and remove the evaluation braces in the template like this

```
<count-up id="feafdcds" duration="1" end-val='promiseObject?promiseObject.value:0' class="number" ></count-up>
```

this will work and set the value of endVal to either promiseObject.value or 0.
Thus you have to be careful that this will bind the value as a string hence the actual value will be either '0' or a string containing the value of promiseObject. you may have to cast this to number again somewhere else then. but this will not update the value of promiseObject outside of the directive.

2. In case you DO need the updated value outside of the directive in your promiseObject as promiseObject.value you have to bind endVal to a variable. so you can keep your

   `endVal: '='`

but you will have to change the template to

```
<count-up id="feafdcds" duration="1" end-val='promiseObject.value' class="number" ></count-up>
```

This way Angular will always update the value of promiseObject.value when endVal changes. but this also means that you will have to take care that promiseObject always exists (and is an object) somewhere in your outer controller.
Furthermore you will have to apply the default value of 0 which you try to grant with your expression somewhere else. You can do this in the outer controller as well for example by initializing promiseObject by

```
promiseObject = {
    value: 0
}
```